# How to Copy a Navigation from Reactjs Website

Tags: reactjs, wordpress

I need to add a WordPress blog to a website created in Reactjs. It's for this website owntrail.com.

I was thinking I can just install WordPress in folder owntrail.com/blog and then copy the html/css navigation and footer from owntrail.com and add it to the WordPress blog so it looks the same as the website.

I tried working on it but my issue is that for some reason when I copy the html,css and js for the navigation from owntrail.com then it shows the whole content of the page.

I know that's probably how Reactjs works but I have zero experience with Reactjs so I'm just trying to see how this can be done.

How would you do this? I'll appreciate any tips or advice.

Thank you!
Josef

Comment: Why not setup the wordpress blog on a subdomain of owntrail.com, then using the REST API of wordpress, fetch blog posts as JSON and render them using the original React components of owntrail. But either way, if you want it to look nice you're going to need to get your hands dirty with react

Comment: Adding on to my comment above ^, or you can create the blog on medium and just embed it onto the blog section of the webpage. Which is a far easier solution, looks better than the WP solution but not as good as the solution I suggested earlier

Comment: Ok thank you. I managed to copy the html and css for the footer. So that works fine. I just need to finish the  header. I can do it the same way as the footer. The only problem is that the navigation needs javascript as well (for the mobile menu). I'm trying to extract just the part the of the javascript necessary for showing the mobile menu.

Comment: They already have a blog on medium but they want their own blog on their website.